# Is there a way to tell a device name (computer name) which connects to the internet jack from a wall without accessing the switch to find out?

Tags: port, switch

I'm not familiar with networking and have been trying to search for info online. From what I have found, there's no possible way to find out the particular physical port of a switch that a computer is connected to w/o accessing the switch?

Am I getting my facts right?

Answer (score 8):

Yes. At least, to the extent of my knowledge. You have two ways of determining the physical port - accessing the switch and determining it logically, or tracing the cable and determining it physically. Both require some form of "access" to the switch.

Answer (score 7):

Depending on the make and model (and configuration) of the switch, it may be possible to get this information from the computer. Most enterprise-class switches (e.g. Cisco Catalyst, HP Procurve, etc.) support one or more network discovery protocols, such as [CDP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cisco_Discovery_Protocol) or [LLDP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link_Layer_Discovery_Protocol). In some cases, they're on by default. The computer normally ignores these discovery protocols, but it's possible to capture the data using a packet sniffer, or in the case with LLDP, actually running an [LLDP server](http://www.kempgen.net/voip/lldp-agents.html).

For example, most of the switches where I work are various Cisco Catalyst models, all of which support CDP. We commonly use a [packet sniffer](http://sidewynder.blogspot.com/2005/07/tcpdump-filter-for-capturing-only.html) to capture CDP packets to determine which switch and port a particular PC is connected to. Though I haven't worked out how to do it, it should be possible to construct a similar filter to capture and decode LLDP packets as well.

Comment: Wireshark can decode both CDP and LLDP. The Port information can be available in both, though it's optional in the protocol specification.

Comment: In LLDP it's mandatory to send a Port ID to the recipient.